# Learning SQL Server 2008 & Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a background in LAMP development and have recently started learning sql server. Whilst the principles of databases are the same, there are a lot of features in SQL Server that are not abundant in or are different to a simple MySQL database, e.g. stored procedures, syntax etc

Can anyone recommend any decent books that encompass the bespoke features possessed by sql server (vs MySQL) perhaps something that is geared towards someone who has underlying knowlegde of RDBMS's..

Comment: MySQL does have stored procedures. While you may not have used them, they do exist.  However, I do find that the use of stored procedures is more prevalent in SQL Server shops, and even more popular in Oracle shops (just based on general observation).  I try to avoid them whenever I can, as there is no compatibility between databases when writing stored procedures, and hence, creates a lot of lock in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 T-SQL Fundamentals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626014) - I got this book when SQL 2008 came out and it gives you a good wrap on what SQL Server Transact SQL can offer you.

Answer (score 1):

Try Paul Nielsen's [Sql Server Bible](http://sqlserverbible.com/), its good enough